# How to Setup Sqlite for HHpc/Windowsce Device in Visual Studio Smart Device Project?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce, smart-device

In winforms application/asp.net  sqlite works if i reference sqlite.dll.

But when i try this to smart Device Project it fails to build because 
of this error:

```
Can't find PInvoke DLL 'SQLite.Interop.DLL'.
```

What did i did is also reference system.Data.SqLite.dll in my project file, add also it windows folder of my device(Windows SE Emulator/Datalogic Memor windows ce 5.0).

Any one here experience this and resolve this problem?
Currently  i am using SQLcompact 3.5 for the handhelds but i encounter drawbacks in terms of speed and capacity and i know that sqlite will solve it.

Thanks in Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got the solution:

We need to Add SQLite.Interop.066.DLL in the project root folder.

Then right click to SQLite.Interop.066.DL to view its properties.

Next Set its Build Action =  Content 
and
             Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer

Rebuild/Build the project and try to test it again.